# Access linked files configuration files - or how to reach the output directory

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration-files

We have a sln with basically the following structure

```
Sln
 |--MyApp.Lib
 |     |-- LotsOfCode
 |--MyApp.Web (old)
 |     |-- SetParameters.DEV.xml
 |     |-- SetParameters.TEST.xml
 |     |-- SetParameters.PROD.xml
 |--MyApp.API (net core)
       |-- appsettings.json
       |-- SetParameters.DEV.xml 
       |-- SetParameters.TEST.xml (link)
       |-- SetParameters.PROD.xml (link)
```

We would like to reuse the settings file in the API project. I've created a custom `ConfigurationProvider` that can read the `SetParameters` files, but I'm unable to get it to run when I add the files as link.

**Problem**: When I add a file as link (and set `type=Content`) it gets copied to the output directory, and I can't seem to figure out a safe way to get that file. Then `IHostinEnvironment` don't seem to know what a `Output` or `bin` directory is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IHostingEnvironment` environment has `WebRootPath` property, which can be used for reading local files like this:

```
using System.IO;

IHostingEnvironment _env;

var pathToFile = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "SetParameters.TEST.xml"));
var settings = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

However, in `ASP.NET Core` you have an opportunity to bind your settings [with `ConfigurationBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration). In a given article one can see `JSON` file usage, however, you can use `AddXmlFile` too. It will be like:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     // set current output path as root
     .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
     // EnvironmentName can be DEV, TEST, PROD, etc
     .AddXmlFile($"SetParameters.{env.EnvironmentName}.xml");

IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
```

After that you can access your parameters like this, given your sample xml:

```
<parameters>
    <settings>
      <param1 name="Test" value="val" />
    </settings>
</parameters>

// will be "val"
configuration["Parameters:param1:value"]
```

I found great article regarding [legacy apps configuration in ASP.NET core](http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects). Other option, more object-oriented, is [to bind your parameters to a model class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects), as described in MSDN article.